# Lua: Creating tables

Tags: lua, key, key-value, lua-table

I'm attempting to use a table as a means to do two things at once.  For example:

```
s = passengers -- user input
t = {[3] = car, [7] = bus, [24] = plane, [45] = train}

for k,v in ipairs t do
    if s = k then
        z = v * 10 -- cost per person
    end
end
```

Now this is extremely basic for what I'm trying to do.  I have a list of about 12 items that each have their own number.  I want to know if I can do what I did above with the table and provide each of the 12 items with their own key value and then use that ?  This key value would represent each items particular, unique number.  Also, can I then use that key's value in a later equation, such as above?

Comment: Yes, you can use the lua-tables as hash indexes

Comment: But you cannot use `ipairs` on a table with "holes" like that. `ipairs` behaviour is defined only for tables that have contiguous indices from 1 to n.

Comment: Also, unless `car`, `bus`, etc. are variables that will create an empty table. You are also missing the `(` and `)` around `t` in the `ipairs` call and you mean `==` and not `=` in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keys are unique, your data structure. The point of a table key is direct access to the corresponding value.

This has the same effect as your loop:

```
local v = t[s] -- value for s or nil if s is not a key
if v != nil then 
    z = v * 10
end
```

(Or, more exactly the same: `local v = rawget(t,s)` to account for cases where `t` has an `__index` metamethod.)

If we can assume that v will never be `false` (which would cause an error at `false * 10`) then it can be written more naturally (which skips that error):

```
local v = t[s]
if v then 
    z = v * 10
end
```